# Using console.log and winston with BST (Alexa SDK)

Tags: javascript, node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I'm using BST to test the Lambdas, but it seems that the tool prevents me from directly printing to the console or logging to a file. If that's not correct, please let me know how I should fix my code. If that is indeed the case, how can I make it work?

In `index.js`, I have a very simple `HelloWorldIntent` that looks like below:

```
var handlers = {
    'HelloWorldIntent': function () {
        console.log('Print this');
        winston.info('info\'ing');
        this.emit(':tell', 'Hello, World!');
    }
};
```

When I place `console.log` and `winston.info` *out* of the `handlers` object (just somewhere in the global scope), and run the script directly on `Node.js`, they work as expected, so that's why I suspect BST is actively preventing the logging operations. Is that the case? If so, how can I work around it?

I run into this issue when testing with `bst speak`.

```
$ bst proxy lambda src/index.js
$ bst speak hello
```

The request and response JSON work fine.

Comment: Hi @posh_pumpkin I am one of the creators of Bespoken Tools....I can probably help you further on our gitter: https://gitter.im/bespoken/bst. But in general, this should show up, and my first question is, are you running the commands in the same terminal? Or different ones? And if so, keep in mind the output should appear in the one where you started the proxy, not the one where you ran the speak command. Perhaps that will help.

Comment: @JohnKelvie I'm using `tmux` to run the commands in the same terminal, but different windows. The `bst speak` command returns the expected JSON, while `bst proxy` doesn't recognize `console.log`. Maybe it's because I haven't set the Application ID (although I don't know why that would matter)? Because every time I test `index.js` the `proxy` pane prints a new `Warning: Application ID is not set` warning. I'll also ask on the gitter if setting the AppID doesn't fix it. Thank you!

Comment: I'm going to give tmux a try...FYI, I tried it with winston as well with no problem, so I don't think that is the issue.